# total of label click on two buttons

Tags: swift, boolean

I have two `UIButton` if I click onto `button1` the value of `label1` is 250, if I click again onto `button1` the value of `label1` should be 0. The same logic is applied to my `button2` and `label2`. I want to store the addition of `label1` and `label2` into `label3`.  . My code is:

```
func PickUpCarCost() {
            if (!isclick){
                imgCheck.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
                isclick=true

                //Pickup fare conver into integer

                let PickUp = String(self.PickUpPrice)
                PickUpFare.text = PickUp
                self.pickCost = Int( PickUpFare.text!)
                self.PAyAmount = ((self.PayFareWithSecurity)+(self.pickCost))
                print("PaybleAmount: \(self.PAyAmount)")
                self.AmountPay1 = ((self.PAyAmount)+(self.DeliverCost))
                PaybleAmount.text=String(self.AmountPay1!)

            }
            else
            {
                imgCheck.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck.png")
                PickUpFare.text = "0"
                self.PickUpElse=Int(PickUpFare.text!)
                print("PickUpElse: \(self.PickUpElse)")
                self.PAyAmount = (self.PayFareWithSecurity)+(self.PickUpElse)
                PaybleAmount.text=String(self.PAyAmount!)
                isclick=false
            }
    }


    func CarDeliverCost() {
        if (!isclick){
            imgUnCheck.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
            isclick=true
            let DeliverPrice = String(self.deliveryPrice)
            DeliverFare.text = DeliverPrice
            self.DeliverCost = Int(DeliverFare.text!)

            self.PAyAmount = ((self.PayFareWithSecurity)+(self.DeliverCost))

            print("PaybleAmount: \(self.PAyAmount)")

            PaybleAmount.text=String(self.PAyAmount!)

        }
        else
        {
            imgUnCheck.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck.png")
            let deliveryelse = String(0)
            DeliverFare.text = deliveryelse
            self.deliver = Int(DeliverFare.text!)
            PaybleAmount.text=String(self.PAyAmount!)
            isclick=false

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am not able to get actual value of label1 and label2 on click or unclick. if btn1 and btn2 both are clicked then how to store self.PAyAmount=self.DeliverCost+self.pickCost if i amclicking both th button then how to get total of it . if value of labes are changing on click or unclick.

Comment: i wants to perform action on click of both button.. and calculate (if both the butons are clucked and unclicked)self.PAyAmount=self.DeliverCost+self.pickCost

Comment: i added the code in answer field. Because i dont konw how to update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue that you're facing is that you are using the same boolean `isClick` for two different scenarios. Your logic is that the user could decide to click onto both buttons or a single one. So if I click onto the first button then your flag is turn on, since the second button also uses the same boolean then you'll get that uncheck behavior automatically.

> Thus you should use two different booleans such as `hasPressOntoFirstButton` and `hasPressOntoSecondButton`, where both set to `false` at the beginning, and each variable is used in their respective scene.

You mentioned that you want to add the `label1` to `label2`, the easier way would be add the variable that set these labels. i.e

```
let label1 = UILabel()
let label2 = UILabel()
let label3 = UILabel()

let data1: Double = 83.0 
let data2: Double = 82.0 

var total: Double { // have a computed variable to adds automatically 
    return data1 + data2 
}

label1.text = "\(data1)"
label2.text = "\(data2)"
label3.text = "\(data1 + data2)" // or "\(total)"
```

Remarks:

(1) your naming convention are really misleading, you should separate `UI object` naming from data. i.e you can have `deliveryFareLabel.text` instead of `DeliverFare.text`

(2) avoid using `!`, unwrapped all optional using either `nil coalescing ??`, or `if let` or `guard statements`

Comment: hi thanks to guiding me. Sir, actullly i am facing a problem, when i click on both the button then i am not getting total of both the label(both labels are in diffrent function  func CarDeliverCost() and 2nd is in func PickUpCarCost() ). i dont know how to implement this logic.